# How to search in google by using java code?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How to search in google by using java code?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999372/google-java-api-for-google-search and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579261/is-there-a-java-api-for-googles-ajax-search-api (?)

Answer (score 4):

I would have told you to use one of their [API](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html). Unfortunatly, there does not seems to exist one for search. As a consequence, you'll have to use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to emulate a browser and go see their results (obviously, you can go the harder way and do some HTTP queries by yourself. But who would do that ?).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the SOAP API has been deprecated. But you can use the **AJAX API** for non-JavaScript purposes as well, see for example:

`http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/using_google_is_ajax_search_api_with_java.php`

*Update Jul 3 2018: This link is now broken; some code from there can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546475/55787, and I found a copy of the article here: https://blog.csdn.net/hgd250/article/details/5214702
Furthermore the orginial link to the AJAX API is now broken, too. It seems that this one is closest to the original meaning: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview?csw=1*

See also this StackOverflow question:

- [google java api for google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999372/google-java-api-for-google-search)

Comment: @LeoNeLeo - thank you for noticing that some links were broken; unfortunately your edit was rejected, but I have removed/replaced them now as well as possible.