# Read Buffered stream website and open the first result Android

Tags: android, search

I have the following code to read a website. The code is searches on google. I want to open automatically the first result and read it again. For the keywords i want the "I am feeling lucky is not working". Please somebody help me find a solution
I have the following code.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/search?q=sample");
   URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
   try {
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     in.close();
   }
 }
```

The query sample is just a sample....

Answer (score 0):

Its already discussed in SO QA :
[How to search in google by using java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652646/how-to-search-in-google-by-using-java-code)

Your approach is also a solution. But it will be complex as it requires parsing of returned HTML.

I think there are some APIS for doing this.

- http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/
- This is deprecated but might still work -->
  http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/

Comment: Your approach is also a solution. But it will be complex as it requires parsing of returned HTML.