# How to search on google using java?

Tags: java, google-api

Is there a way to search on google using java, and if yes can I only search using words like example if I was trying to search on google "stack overflow" it would show stack overflow as a search, but can I do it with java?

Comment: Google search in the web let’s you search only stackoverflow by using the right search terms. First learn that. Then learn how to use java to call a web API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search in google by using java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652646/how-to-search-in-google-by-using-java-code)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code!

```
String myUserAgent="your useragent"; //you gotta get your useragent here
String GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL = "https://www.google.com/search";
String searchURL = GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "?as_q=stack+overflow";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).userAgent(myUserAgent).get();
```

Here are the libraries

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
```

I am copypasting from a huge data scraping code I made (in Java), so let me know if I am forgetting something!